# I need to get the folder path,how to select a folder using fileupload in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

I want to select the folder using the file upload control and i need to just get the folder path that is to be saved.I think it is not possible to select a folder using file upload control but i think it is possible by some kind of customization. 
Please anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to file path without file name . here you can get just path not name !

```
string[] Dir = FileUpload1.FileName.Split('\\');
            string Path="";
            for (int i = 0; i < Dir.Length; i++)
                Path += Dir[i] + "\\";
```

after this you can use Path for folder path!

Comment: I dont want to select the file and split it, i need to select a folder for getting the folder path

Comment: file upload control should be get file only , Not a folder

Comment: Is there is any control or any kind of customization is possible to select a folder to get the folder path.

Answer (score 1):

`FileUpload` control can upload a single file only at a time which then takes the Full file path.

At first, One solution ( which doesn't seems feasible at all)  comes in mind is to use multiple FileUpload controls, but definitely the question is: different folders can have a varying number of files, so what number of FileUpload controls to use.[  Of course, there can be many other reasons too for avoiding this solution. ]

So far to make sure we upload all files of a folder in one go, is to create a custom User Control which allows to select multiple files and upload them in one go.

Check [**`this article`**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24271/Multiple-File-Upload-User-Control) on achieving the same. This [**`another Link2`**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15742/Multiple-File-Upload-With-Progress-Bar-Using-Flash) may be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

to select multiple file file upload property Allow Multiple="True,False"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to select the folder in asp.net

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" webkitdirectory directory multiple />
```